# How to change the opacity of an image when another image is touched?

Tags: swift, swiftui

After searching, I discovered the instance method onTapGesture that can perform some action when an image is touched. However, I try to implement it so that anytime I touch an image, another image's opacity is changed. How can I do so ? I have the following code.

```
struct LycéesRow: View {
    var lycée: Lycée

    @State private var isTouched = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            let firstImage = lycée.image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .offset(y: -35)

            firstImage

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
            .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
            .offset(y: -35)


            let secondImage = lycée.image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 355, height: 200)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .offset(x: 5)
            .offset(y: 39.8)
            .opacity(isTouched ? 0.0 : 1.0)
            .onTapGesture {
                isTouched.toggle()
            }

            secondImage

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                Text(lycée.département + ", France")
                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(0.5)

                Text(lycée.nom)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                .foregroundColor(.white)

                Text(lycée.ville)
                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(0.9)
            }
            .offset(y: -30)
            .offset(x: 12)
        }
    }
}
```

I want that when I touch the first image, the second image's opacity goes to 0.0. How can I do so ? Also, when I touch the second image and that it gets blurred, unfortunately, it doesn't redirect me to my other view that I defined in another file and it only lowers the opacity image, but doesn't act like a click too.

Comment: Please clarify your question, you want to tap the first image and change the opacity of the second one, but the code shows that the second image is the one with the tap gesture.

Comment: I want that when I tap any of these, whether the first or the second, only the second image's opacity goes to 0.0 @Claudio

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to achieve that and here's an example to understand how it works.

```
struct ExampleView() {
    @State private var isTouched: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("image-1")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .onTapGesture {
                    isTouched.toggle()
                }
            Image("image-2")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                // If 'isTouched' is true it's 0.0
                // If 'isTouched' is false it's 1.0
                .opacity(isTouched ? 0.0 : 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's another.

```
struct ExampleView() {
    @State private var customOpacity: Double = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("image-1")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .onTapGesture {
                    customOpacity = 0.0
                }
            Image("image-2")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .opacity(customOpacity)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. But I realized that it actually won't change anything if I touch the first image, cause it's under the rounded rectangle, so I applied to method to the rounded rectangle, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two options the first is two move the tap gesture recogniser to the first image because it contains the second image and make sure the second image and the blurred view don't respond to clicks (`.allowsHitTesting(false)`)

```
struct LycéesRow: View {
    var lycée: Lycée

    @State private var isTouched = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            let firstImage = lycée.image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .offset(y: -35)
            .onTapGesture {
                isTouched.toggle()
            }

            firstImage

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
            .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
            .offset(y: -35)
            .allowsHitTesting(false)


            let secondImage = lycée.image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 355, height: 200)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .offset(x: 5)
            .offset(y: 39.8)
            .opacity(isTouched ? 0.0 : 1.0)
            .allowsHitTesting(false)

            secondImage

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                Text(lycée.département + ", France")
                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(0.5)

                Text(lycée.nom)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                .foregroundColor(.white)

                Text(lycée.ville)
                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(0.9)
            }
            .offset(y: -30)
            .offset(x: 12)
        }
    }
}
```

The second approach (and cleaner) is to set the gesture recogniser on the zstack like this:

```
struct LycéesRow: View {
    var lycée: Lycée

    @State private var isTouched = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            let firstImage = lycée.image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .offset(y: -35)


            firstImage

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
            .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
            .offset(y: -35)

            let secondImage = lycée.image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 355, height: 200)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .offset(x: 5)
            .offset(y: 39.8)
            .opacity(isTouched ? 0.0 : 1.0)

            secondImage

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                Text(lycée.département + ", France")
                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(0.5)

                Text(lycée.nom)
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                .foregroundColor(.white)

                Text(lycée.ville)
                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(0.9)
            }
            .offset(y: -30)
            .offset(x: 12)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isTouched.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works. However, once tapped and everything goes like I want (opacity lowers), it doesn't redirect me to what I defined in another file (I can send it to you). Why does it just lower the opacity but doesn't act like a click on something that is supposed to redirect me ? @Claudio

Comment: I have a navigation view of the rectangles I showed you in the original post. `ForEach(lycées) { lycée in
                        NavigationLink {
                            LycéeDétail(lycée: lycée)
                        } label: {
                            LycéesRow(lycée: lycée)
                        }
                    }`As you can see, when I click the rectangles or image or whatever, I'm supposed to be redirected to LycéeDétail. Why is not happening ?